# Открыть батник с помощью кнпоки в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, button, bat

Я не понимаю как в Unity2D сделать так что бы когда я нажимал на кнопку открывался файл с папки путь которого я указал к примеру: OpenFile("Туть путь");

Если не поняли то я хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку в юнити открывался файл.

Answer (score 0):

В юнити доступен класс [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0).
Пример:

```
string pathToFile = @"нужный\вам\путь.bat";
Process proc = new Process(pathToFile);
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку что делать?

Comment: (10,15): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
(10,17): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
(10,16): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.

Comment: @Давид C# учить, этот код в метод надо вставлять, а вы куда вставили? https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ

Comment: В скрипт добавил

Comment: Даже когда я сохряняю ошибку дает

Comment: Сделал. Теперь такая ошибка error CS1729: 'Process' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Видимо, в Unity немного изменено API для процессов. Посмотрите ответ на аналогичный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885150/run-a-exe-file-with-arguments-from-unity-using-c-sharp